433MHz receive circuit with two antennas?
First of all, a bit of context - the receiver in question is a CAME gate opener, that receives commands from 433MHz remotes (like CAME models TOP432/TOP434). As is typical with such devices, the receiving antenna was located on a signal light installed inside of the gate.
After a recent "upgrade", which involved adding another signal light (with another attached antenna) outside the gate, the range of the existing remotes went from 40-50 meters to something like 15-20. When asking the installers, they said that "they spliced the cable and connected it to both the existing antenna (on the old signal light) and the new one (on the new light)". "
Now my RF knowledge is very limited, but this seems... wrong.
So I am asking the more knowledgeable people here - is this the right design? Or could this be at least part of the reason for the dramatic decrease in the remote range?
Thank you!
[ Edit: I am looking for one of two things:

either someone tells me that I am wrong, and this is the correct way of doing things (in which case I will kindly ask for additional help in figuring out why the range drastically decreased)
an explanation of why the installation is wrong, which I can take to the installers asking for a change.
]


There are ways to combine signal from two antennas like that, but you do have to do it right. It's more complicated than just splicing two wires together arbitrarily.

If I understand correctly, you would want one combiner and one divider. That would result in the best performance. But as with many antenna installations, doing it nonoptimally will usually result in things kinda sorta working.

@Hearth - I am pretty sure nobody looked at things like cable length (especially considering the fact that the existing cable is hidden in the wall... :) )

@Fred - not sure I understand - what do you mean by "one combiner and one divider"?

And what exactly is the actual"splice" in this context? Is it RF coupler product, a "T adapter" with 3 RF connectors (likely BNC, TNC or some such) or someone connecting 3 peeled coax stumps with Wago clips?

@Lundin - I will ask about the splice details, but based on my experience so far I am pretty sure it is "we took both cables and stuck them into the controller antenna connector"... :) (so pretty much the latter option you presented)

Just go and have a look at it? Overall you need to provide more details about the installation for anyone to give a qualified answer which isn't just based on guessing. Antenna types, cable lengths, types of connectors etc.

Unfortunately, this is a shared gate, and I do not have physical access to the installation. But I will do my best to get the details. To answer your other questions: the antennas are the typical omnidirectional ones ( see CAME 001TOP-A433N as an example). The cable lengths are around 2-3 meters (a bit more for the external, recently installed, antenna)
